# How to automatically generate optimised regexp from list of strings it should match

Tags: regex

Recently I was looking for a regexp which can detect user agent connecting to my webapp is a crawler.

There are many crawlers like google, yahoo, bing, facebook and many others and they advertise themselves in the User-Agent header. So basically I thought a reglexp could be compiled that would try to match any of these substrings in a given string. It can be matched trivially with regexp like google|yahoo|bing|facebook, but if the list of given strings is large enough and many of them have similar prefixes or suffixes than maybe a more efficient regexp could be compiled. (for this exact purpose there are human compiler regexs floating on the internetz).

So, is there a tool or algorithm one could use in situation like this which would, given a list of words, return a regexp which would determine if any of the words matches in the input string?

P.S.
I was reminded of this as something very similar was posted today on the ycombinator http://regex.inginf.units.it/, solver using genetic algorithm. And it seems that in the general case it might be NP hard problem, but it would still be usefull if it worked for a simple list of 20-30 words..

Comment: I think you need to share some possibilities to be searched for so that we can help you start.

Comment: The optimisation is automatically done when compiling the regex, so passing in the trivial expression is OK.

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare to maintain. Are you seeing performance problems with your regex that have prompted the need for optimization?

Answer (score 2):

The [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)  used in fgrep does almost exactly this, though it builds an internal data structure to do the matching rather than generating a regexp. There are implementations for C, Python, etc on the Wikipedia paged linked to there, so you could include that in your crawler. You would compile the data structure once, and use the compiled version to test every user-agent.

Comment: this is somethig like what i had in mind, except it matches directly and does not build regexp